# SPO Calculate Total Cost Per Group View

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, calculated-column, view, calculated-column-formula

I will try to summarize my main goal if it's possible to achieve it.

I have a list which contains the following columns:

**Invoice ID Number, Item Name, Quantity, Item Cost,Total Cost.**

What i want to achieve is the following:

- I want to add multiple items in the same invoice.

**For Example:**

Invoice ID 1 contains, Item Name: Shoes, Quantity: 1, Item Cost: 10$.

Now in the same **Invoice ID 1** i want to add more items so the invoice now will be:

**Item Name: Shoes, Quantity: 1, Item Cost: 10$.**

**Item Name: Shirt, Quantity:2, Item Cost:30$.**

**2.** Now when i click save, i want the Total Cost column calculate the Items cost added to the invoice automatically per group, and showing the total cost of all the invoices similar to this one:

[image: SumCost]

I have found [this](https://www.metrostarsystems.com/enterprise-it/sharepoint-calculated-column-total/) tutorial but seems that the formula is outdated.

Any suggestions how to achieve the following workflow ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add multiple items in the same invoice, create a column named "Invoice ID" , don't choose "Enforce unique values".

To calculate the Items cost added to this invoice automatically, modify view, group by "Invoice ID", sum "Item Cost":
[image]

It will calculate the Items cost added to this invoice automatically:
[image]